# Using jQuery Labelify + jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the Labelify plugin to have a light grey label inside my text fields. The plugin uses the title attribute for the inside text. I'm also using the Validation plugin for validating that particular field.

When the validation fails, the validator produces an error, which it gets from the title attribute of that field as well. How would I make a custom error for that field rather than it automatically taking the title attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
<tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30"/>

    <p class="error"></p>

    </td>

</tr>
```

And in you validation portion

```
$('#category').validate({

    rules:{name: {required: true}},

    messages: {name: "Category name is required"},      

    errorPlacement: function(error, element){

            $(element).each(function (){

            $(this).parent('td').find('p.error').html(error);

        });

}})
```

Where `#category` is a form id

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this: [Jquery Validation plug-in custom error placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969381/jquery-validation-plug-in-custom-error-placement)