# What is the name of this jQuery form validation plugin? (Screenshot included)

Tags: jquery, validation

I am looking for a good jquery plugin for form validation. I have found many related plugins but not of them matches the one I'm after. Below is a screenshot of what I'm looking for. Can anyone provide me with a link or the name of the plugin?

[image]

I've looked through the following links but they do not look like the one I am looking for:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation
- http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
- http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/
- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/powerful-jquery-form-validation-plugin-validity/
- http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/
- http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html
- http://frontendbook.com/jquery-form-validation-plugin

Comment: If you've already gone through all those, I don't think you're going to find one that satisfies you. Probably easier to just write it yourself.

Comment: I suppose you made a screenshot off an existing page, did you? What is the URL of that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not even be an off-the-shelf jquery plugin.

That design could certainly be created with the jQuery Validation plugin. You will just have to manually manage your error containers. Some good info here:

[Jquery Validation plug-in custom error placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969381/jquery-validation-plug-in-custom-error-placement)

Answer (score 0):

its html5 validation popups . If you specify `novalidate="novalidate"` in form , it will not show

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could tried this one:
http://git.aaronlumsden.com/progression/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.