# bootstrap input group btn pushed down after jquery validation kicks in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap styled form:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="formEmail">User Email</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control" data-rule-emailRequired="true" name="email" id="formEmail">
                    <option value="default">Please Select Users</option>
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="addUserBtn" type="button">Create User</button>
                </span>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="newUserBtn" type="button">Add User</button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <ul id="issueUserList" class="list-group list-inline"></ul>
        </div>
```

as you can see it has a data rule validation, when this returns false and the error message pops up it pushes the input-group-btn below see next image
[image]

my CSS is

```
.input-validation-error { border: 2px solid red; }

.field-validation-error { color: red; }

label.error {
    color: red;
}
input.error, textarea.error, select.error {
    color: black;
    background-color: #ebccd1;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    border: 2px solid red;
}


div #loading {
    display: none;
}

.input-group {width: 100%}
#issueTable_length {
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 2%;
}
```

Could someone give me any advice or tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give us a link? Or is the file local?

Comment: Am afraid the web is still local do you require any more information i can provide?

Comment: Is that all CSS and HTML? Any js?

Comment: That is all the CSS. HTML there is more JS nothing on that besides the validation, the rest of the HTML is just the rest of the form do you need that as well?

Comment: Don't think so, try adding `margin-bottom: -15px` to the error thing

Comment: Am afraid that didnt change anything.

Comment: Add a space between required and data-rule-email on the select, I really don't know...

Comment: i made a small test if i remove the error label with jquery they return on the normal position data-rule-emailRequired is the name of the validation class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133663/discussion-between-tinsten-and-avaloth-oath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution was to make custom error labels and append the error message there. i have followed this instructions to solve my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044251/6603342

Answer (score 1):

Javascript/jquery classes that fires the validation (.input-validation-error in this case) should be applied to whole input-group element and not just to select element.

Comment: Hi i have done that but the same behaviour still occurs.